# Monitor.TryEnter / Monitor.Exit and SynchronizationLockException

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Is it possible to detect if the same thread trying to release the lock?
We have many places in code that looks like:

```
try
{
    try
    {
       if(!Monitor.TryEnter(obj, 2000)) 
       { 
            throw new Exception("can not lock"); 
       }
    }
    finally
    {
       Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
catch
{
    //Log
}
```

The above code very simplified, and actually Enter and Exit statement located in custom object (lock manager).

The problem, that in that structure, we have `SynchronizationLockException` when trying to "Exit", since it looks like the thread that not succeed to lock, tries to release in finally.

So the question, is how I can know if the thread who making Monitor.Exit is the same thread who did Monitor.Enter?
I thought that I can use CurrentThread.Id to sync enter and exit, but I'm not sure if it "safe" enough.

Comment: Since you declared that the actually Enter and Exit statement are located in custom object, I'd like to know if you can access `obj` in the outter block?

Comment: No, in outer block i have no reference to object, since the lock manager receives "key" as a parameter and creates it's own object for lock. You can see my lock manager in my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030491/net-multithreading-lock-object-with-log-when-locked-for-to-much-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you think that to put the calling of Monitor.Exit in try-catch was 'durty'(dirty?), here's a very simple idea trying to 'take the durty away'. Lock is reentrant for the same thread and if one thread acquired successfully, before it releases, attempt from another thread will fail. So that you can consider something like:

```
public void Exit(object key) {
    if(!IsActive) {
        return;
    }

    if(LockDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
        var syncObject=LockDictionary[key];

        if(Monitor.TryEnter(syncObject.SyncObject, 0)) {
            SetLockExit(syncObject);
            Monitor.Exit(syncObject.SyncObject);
            Monitor.Exit(syncObject.SyncObject);
        }
    }
}
```

We call Monitor.Exit twice because we lock it twice, one in the code outer, and one just here.

Comment: Hmm...very nice "clean" solution:) It looks very simple and like it should work well for my case! Thank you very much! BTW, 'durty' is 'dirty' - sorry for my ugly English :))

Comment: If `LockDictionary` is a `Dictionary<,>` here, you need to be aware that it's not thread-safe. I still think fixing the code rather than working around its brokenness would be a better idea.

Comment: @Ken Kin, could you explain, why it's not possible for a thread that failed with first TryEnter  to enter the lock second time? At the time of starting to execute the finally block, another thread can already leave it.

Comment: @mistika: The equivalence code was wrong, I've removed.

Answer (score 19):

> So the question, is how I can know if the thread who making Monitor.Exit is the same thread who did Monitor.Enter?

You can't, easily, as far as I'm aware. You can't find out which thread owns a monitor.

However, this is just a *coding* issue - you should change your code so that it doesn't even *attempt* to release the monitor when it shouldn't. So your code above could be rewritten as:

```
if (!Monitor.TryEnter(obj, 2000))
{
    throw new Exception(...);
}
try
{
    // Presumably other code
}
finally
{
     Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

Or even better, if you're using .NET 4, use the [overload of `TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679.aspx) which accepts an `ret` parameter:

```
bool gotMonitor = false;
try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(obj, ref gotMonitor);
    if (!gotMonitor)
    {
        throw new Exception(...);
    }
    // Presumably other code
}
finally
{
    if (gotMonitor)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the post, seems that the internal try-finally was not intended to be modified.

Comment: @KenKin, yep, try-catch should not be modified, but it looks like it not possible to achieve what I need in current code structure. I thought about it, but still hoped to solve it :) Jon, thanks for clear answer, now we need to decide if remove using of TryEnter and use Enter instead, or we need to refactor huge amount of code.

Comment: @KenKin: Given that it's *broken*, I think it's reasonable to say it basically has to be modified...

Comment: @AlexDn: Fundamentally, your code is broken. I would strongly recommend fixing it rather than trying to work around it. It's not clear *why* it should take a lot of effort though - do you have this pattern in lots of places? If so, the first thing to refactor would be that - see if you can work out a way of representing the control flow in a single place (e.g. passing in a delegate to execute within the lock if it could be acquired).

Comment: When we first developed the LockManager, it only used Monitor.Enter and we had no problem with SynchronizationLockException, but then we found that some locks are locked for too much time and decided to replace the Enter with TryEnter in order to not block code execution. But we didn't thought that the structure that worked good with Enter will not work with TryEnter without refactor. Before we made a change, this structure was used intensively in many methods and now it's not an easy task (from time perspective) to refactor it. Anyway, I agree that the code is broken and need to be fixed :)

Comment: @KenKin you mean lock the dictionary when adding new object per key? If it is that what you mean, than this is already done inside lock manager (dictionary is locked when new object id added). If I didn't understand you, can you please give me more details in the LockManager thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030491/net-multithreading-lock-object-with-log-when-locked-for-to-much-time).

Comment: Jon, Sorry for unaccepting the answer, but Ken Kin's solution looks very nice and it not involves code refactor. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @AlexDn: I still say you're basically working your way around broken code. It's like catching `NullReferenceException` instead of fixing your code to avoid dereferencing a null value - yes, it works, but it would be better to "heal" the code than put a sticking plaster over it.

Comment: I do believe Jon points out the correct way of coding. I've just provide a trick to solve it without refactor.

Comment: @KenKin I agree with Jon, to. I'm sure we will find the time to refactor the code, but for now you provided real solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but here's my answer anyway.
I would move the try-finally construct inside the if:

```cs
try
{
    if(Monitor.TryEnter(obj, 2000))
    {
        try
        {
            // code here
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(obj);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't acquire lock");
    }
}
catch
{
    // log
}
```