# Writing a sync application using Windows Service to process files in Parallel

Tags: c#, windows-services, synchronization

I have a folder on my windows server, where people will be uploading CSV files to, `C:\Uploads`.

I want to write a simple windows service application that will scan this uploads folder (every 5 seconds) and collect the files in and process them in parallel (Thread /per File?). However, the main scanning process should not overlap, i.e. locking is required.

So, I was experimenting with it like this:
*I am aware this is not windows service code, it's a console app to test ideas...*

**Updated Code, based on dcastro's reply**

```
class Program
{
    static Timer _InternalTimer;
    static Object _SyncLock = new Object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _InternalTimer = new Timer(InitProcess, null, 0, 5000); // Sync cycle is every 5 sec

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void InitProcess(Object state)
    {
        ConsoleLog("Starting Process");
        StartProcess();
    }

    static void StartProcess()
    {
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(_SyncLock, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                ConsoleLog("Lock Acquired. Doing some dummy work...");

                List<string> fileList = new List<string>()
                {
                    "fileA.csv",
                    "fileB.csv"
                };

                Parallel.ForEach(fileList, (string fileName) =>
                {
                    ConsoleLog("Processing File: " + fileName);
                    Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10 sec to process each file
                });

                GC.Collect();
            }
            else
                ConsoleLog("Sync Is Busy, Skipping Cycle");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
                Monitor.Exit(_SyncLock);
        }
    }

    static void ConsoleLog(String Message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}]: {1}",
            DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"),
            Message);
    }
}
```

When it runs, it looks like this:

[image]

Does this look right? Any help/tips on improving this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine to me, apart from the fact that you don't need to start a task with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. The `System.Threading.Timer` already executes your callback on the ThreadPool, so there's no need to launch yet another task that will also be run on the thread pool.

Also, if your timer ticks every 5 seconds, and you expect it to take about 10 secs to process the files, then your threads will begin to queue up waiting for the lock to be released. That happened on the example you posted.

If this is the case, I would either increase the timer's period to more than 10 secs, or use [`Monitor.TryEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of a regular `lock`. `TryEnter` will try to acquire the lock, and return immediately regardless of whether or not the lock was taken. If the lock is currently taken by another thread, you just skip this tick entirely.

---

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the feedback. The sync is meant to run every 5 minutes. The reason why the task takes 10 seconds is because the processing of files can take however long (say there was 100 files to process). That's why the locking is in place to do the process only when it's not already processing. Based on your feedback, I updated my code and it seems to be broken now: http://pastebin.com/ZBuCmEyq (when the sync runs, the first cycle works, but the app closes/exits when the 2nd cycle begins (i am not getting sync is busy message)...

Comment: @LatheesanKanes The `_LockAcquired` variable should be local to the method, not static. Let me know if that works.

Comment: apologies, I did not realise. Whilst waiting for your reply, I started to look at how to solve this and came up with the following: http://pastebin.com/aSa9M9dh which appears to work like this: http://i.imgur.com/kHlXrK7.png (is this now okay? or should I go back to my other code I posted on above reply and use a local variable)? P.S. I meant `5 Seconds` not `5 Minutes` on my first reply.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Did you find that somewhere? That looks *really* nasty... There's no reason to throw an exception and then catch it immediately, and then enter the lock just to release it again.. it's a mess. Yeah, go back to what you had and declare the bool just before the `try` block.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes This works fine for me: http://dotnetfiddle.net/SG24hC (I reduced the timer period to 1sec and the file processing time to 2secs)

Comment: I found that nested try idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14100254/2332336. I am going to try your suggestion.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Notice that the answer below, by Jon Skeet, got +5 votes instead of +1 ^^ Jon presents two solutions, the second solution is exactly the same as mine.

Comment: Thanks dcastro, your suggestion works as expected. Much appreciated.