# Windows Service with Parallel Task - stopping service gracefully

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

This is a follow-up from my previous question here: [Writing a sync application using Windows Service to process files in Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674392/writing-a-sync-application-using-windows-service-to-process-files-in-parallel)

I've got the timing and processing correctly setup exactly as I want. When the service is installed and I start it, so it's doing some work and then stop it randomly, I had a windows service stop error and I found the following error in the Event Viewer:

```
Application: SyncTest.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException
Stack:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int32, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1<Int32>, System.Action`2<Int32,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState>, System.Func`4<Int32,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<System.__Canon>, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState>, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,Int64>, System.Func`4<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`5<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,Int64,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`2<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState>, System.Action`3<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,Int64>, System.Func`4<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`5<System.__Canon,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,Int64,System.__Canon,System.__Canon>, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>, System.Action`1<System.__Canon>)
   at SyncTest.StartProcess(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```

This is my code so far:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
{
    static Timer _SyncTimer;
    static Object _SyncLock = new Object();

    public Service()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Init
        ConsoleLog("--- Sync Initializing ---");
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Every 5 Seconds
        _SyncTimer = new Timer(StartProcess, null, 0, 5000);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        // Stop Timer
        if (null != _SyncTimer)
        {
            ConsoleLog("### Stopping Process ###");
            try
            {
                _SyncTimer.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                _SyncTimer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    static void StartProcess(Object state)
    {
        ConsoleLog("### Starting Process ###");
        bool lockTaken = false;
        try
        {
            Monitor.TryEnter(_SyncLock, ref lockTaken);
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                ConsoleLog("Lock Acquired. Doing some dummy work...");

                List<string> fileList = new List<string>()
                {
                    "fileA.csv",
                    "fileB.csv"
                };

                Parallel.ForEach(fileList, (string fileName) =>
                {
                    ConsoleLog("Processing File: " + fileName);
                    Thread.Sleep(10000); // 10 sec to process each file
                });

                GC.Collect();
            }
            else
                ConsoleLog("Sync Is Busy, Skipping Cycle");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
                Monitor.Exit(_SyncLock);
        }
    }

    static void ConsoleLog(String Message)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"C:\SyncTest\application.log"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("[{0}]: {1}",
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"),
                Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It does appear to start and stop from the windows services correctly:

```
[01/22/2014 08:22:58 AM]: --- Sync Initializing ---
[01/22/2014 08:22:58 AM]: ### Starting Process ###
[01/22/2014 08:22:58 AM]: Lock Acquired. Doing some dummy work...
[01/22/2014 08:22:58 AM]: Processing File: fileA.csv
[01/22/2014 08:22:58 AM]: Processing File: fileB.csv
[01/23/2014 08:23:04 AM]: ### Starting Process ###
[01/23/2014 08:23:04 AM]: Sync Is Busy, Skipping Cycle
[01/23/2014 08:23:06 AM]: ### Stopping Process ###
[01/23/2014 08:23:50 AM]: --- Sync Initializing ---
[01/23/2014 08:23:50 AM]: ### Starting Process ###
[01/23/2014 08:23:50 AM]: Lock Acquired. Doing some dummy work...
[01/23/2014 08:23:50 AM]: Processing File: fileA.csv
[01/23/2014 08:23:50 AM]: Processing File: fileB.csv
[01/23/2014 08:23:55 AM]: ### Starting Process ###
[01/23/2014 08:23:55 AM]: Sync Is Busy, Skipping Cycle
[01/23/2014 08:23:58 AM]: ### Stopping Process ###
```

How can I stop the sync gracefully? I.e. allow the current `Parallel.Foreach` to finish before the sync stops the timer and stop the sync "cycles"?

---

**Update**

After doing some further reading, I read somewhere on SO that you can use the `lock object` and `Monitor.TryEnter` to wait for current process to finish before exiting like this:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    ConsoleLog("### Stopping Process ###");
    bool lockTaken = false;
    try
    {
        Monitor.TryEnter(_SyncLock, ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            try
            {
                _SyncTimer.Dispose();
            }
            catch { }
            finally
            {
                _SyncTimer = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
        else
            ConsoleLog("Sync Is Busy, Waiting To Stop");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (lockTaken)
            Monitor.Exit(_SyncLock);
    }
}
```

This appears to be working (I no longer see errors), but I am unsure if this is the correct way to go about this....

Comment: I am going to upvote purely to see unicorns...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth dude it's Unicoins lol

Comment: I'll take a Tuesday morning thumbs up from a Unicorn after the sleepless night I had with my screaming 10 month old... lol

Comment: Can you use VS2012/2013 for this? If so, I could show how it can be done easily and efficiently using `async/await` and `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @avo - What does visual studio version has to do anything with `async/await` / `Task.Delay`? Do you mean to check if I am using .Net 4? Yes I am, do show :)

Comment: VS2012-13 comes with C# 5.0, which has language support for `async/await`. It greatly simplifies asynchronous and multithreaded programming. You can still target .NET 4.0 (with `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`), but you do need the C# 5.0 compiler. Stay tuned :)